# Lock in dropdown selection

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm creating a quiz.

Questions on one worksheet and the answers on another.

When a question is answered another field with this formula

```
=IF(C5="","",IF(C5=Answers!A5,"Correct","Incorrect"))
```

tells the person if the answer is correct or incorrect.

I am using data validation with dropdown lists so they can only choose true/false, (a, b, c, d) etc.

Is there a way to lock in a selected answer, until a master reset button is pressed?

For example,

- Question is in A1
- The possible answers are in the form of a dropdown menu in B1.
- Sometimes the answer is in the form of a true false, sometime it is in the form of a multiple choice. In the example of true false, if the person puts in true, c3 will say correct or if they put false, then incorrect.
- As it is now, the person can switch back and forth as much as they want.

I am looking to make it so once an answer is selected, they cannot change it.

Comment: Yes using vba in a worksheet change event to un-protect the sheet, lock the target cell then re-protect the sheet, making sure they cannot select protected cells.

Comment: Sorry I don't think i made myself clear on my request. Im not asking how to protect cells from them changing the formulas. Im asking if the cells with the dropdown menu, how to lock in answer, so for example if they choose true, they cant change it to false later on.

Comment: Unfortunately, this can't be done with data validation alone. What @ScottCraner recommended is what you'll need to use if that's what you need. Side note: if you have Office 365, have you checked out Microsoft Forms? That might be easier for you and your users and should handle for what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Sheet Protection, combined with Range Locking and a Change event.

Put this code in the relevant `Worksheet` Module.  Adjust the `Private` constants to suit your needs.

```
Option Explicit

' Reference the cells that your users may enter data into
Private Const DataCells As String = "J1,J3,J5"
Private Const PW As String = "password"

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim DataRange As Range

    Set DataRange = Me.Range(DataCells)
    'Loop thru changed cells
    For Each cl In Target.Cells
        'If changed cell is in the DataCells range and is not blank, lock it
        If Not Application.Intersect(cl, DataRange) Is Nothing Then
            If Not IsEmpty(cl) Then
                Me.Unprotect PW
                Target.Locked = True
                Me.Protect PW
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

'Re-enable data entry to all DataCells
Sub MasterReset()
    'Unlock the sheet, prompt for password
    Me.Unprotect
    'Unlock the cells
    Me.Range(DataCells).Locked = False
    'Optional, clear DataCells
    Me.Range(DataCells).ClearContents
    'Lock the sheet again
    Me.Protect PW
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, ill give this a try tomorrow.

Comment: @Gehn47 any feedback on why this didn't solve your problem?

Comment: So I found a great article that helped me and also kind of explain. Here is the article.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3778-excel-lock-cell-after-data-entry-input.html

The problem im having now is when a user enters the input, its locking all the cells, instead of just the one they entered data into.

Comment: Sorry I just started learning VBA a few about a year back so im still relatively new. I apologize.

Comment: I havent had a chance to fully implement your code section. Sorry this is a side project in addition to my normal job so I dont get full time to work on it.

Comment: @Gehn47 No problem, just curious why the un-accept. That article is broadly similar to my answer.  With respect to _The problem im having now is when a user enters the input, its locking all the cells, instead of just the one they entered data into_ that article is locking a whole range (`A1:F8`), my code specifically only locks the cell  that changed, and only if it appears in a specified list (`"J1,J3,J5"` in my example.  You will of course change that to list the cells _you_ want to manage)

Answer (score 1):

This works pretty good:

In the "This Workbook" module, insert the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Sheet1.Protect userinterfaceonly:=True 'allows macros to run
    Sheet1.Range("A1:A20").Locked = False 'replace this range with the range the user deals with.

End Sub
```

In the sheet module that the user will be interacting with, add this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Locked = True Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Locked = False Then
        If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
        If Target.Value <> "" Then Target.Locked = True
    End If

End Sub
```

That should take care of things for you!

Comment: Why `SelectionChange`?  and not an actual value change?  That's a lot of code running as the user moves around the sheet for no effect.

Comment: I ran into an error when I was testing it but it was totally unrelated looking back, thanks for your comment! I changed the answer to reflect this!